# Computing the lengths of the obtained trapezium

Tags: geometry, quadrilateral

$ABCD$ is a quadrilateral. A line through $D$ parallel to $AC$ meets $BC$ produced at $P$. My book asked me to show that the area of $APB$ and $ABCD$, are the same, which I did. But it aroused my interest. So I researched on **how do we compute the sides or simply characterize the trapezium $ACPD$**, if we know the sides and angles of $ABCD$. But I was not able to find any result. Please help.

Comment: (1) From my drawing, It should be the area of APB and ABCD are the same. (2) This is a standard question on transforming a quadrilateral to triangle having the same area. (3) The theorem to be used is "equal base and equal altitude gives equal area (for triangles)". That has nothing to do with angles.

Comment: @Mick Oh yes, you are right. I meant APB.

Comment: @Mick And the main question is the part in bold. That I had done on my own.

Comment: Will try to work on that.

Comment: @Mick Any progress? It is an interesting question isn't it?

Comment: Yes to the progress and yes also to the question is interesting and I have never thought of that. Just give me some time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to the following figure:-
[image]

Notation:-  [Object] = area of that object.

using the formula, ⊿ = (1/2) ab sin θ,

[quad ABCD] = … 
= f(a, b, c, d, θ, Ø)
= f, a function depending on the mentioned variables

[ABP] = (1/2) H (b + x) = (1/2) a sin θ (b + x)

[quad ABCD] = [ABP] implies  $\frac{a \sin \theta (b + x)}{ 2} = f$

∴ $(b + x) = \frac {2f} {\sin \theta}$ or $x = \frac {2f} {\sin \theta} – b$

Thus, ⊿ABP can be completely solved, provided a, b, c, d, θ, Ø are known.

We now try to see if some of the givens can be relaxed.

(1) If ABCD is a trapezium with AD // BC, the requirement can be relaxed to a, b, c, d, θ only because [ABCD] can be calculated by the extended Heron formula without the presence of Ø.

(2) In fact, As AC = g(a, b, θ), using the cosine law.

And Ø = h(AC, c, d).

This means Ø need not be known.

Hence, we can conclude that:-

If a quadrilateral has its 4 sides and an angle known, the components of the transformed triangle having the same area can be completely soklved.

Comment: @user2028943 Sorry for the late reply because this has to be done after work. You are welcome for further questions.

Answer (score 1):

Edit：

[image]

It is easy find all for $ACPD$, $AC$ is trivial to get. then you can have $F$, since $AB$ is known,so $AF,FB,FC$ can be obtained. then you can find $CP,DP$ since $AC$  \\  $DP$

Comment: And then? Did you understood my question?

Comment: I proved what I think you are trying to suggest. But my question is the one in bold, does it follow from you hint, how?

Comment: @user2028943 OK, I misunderstand your question and I edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks, but I have accepted Mick s and I cant vote up because I do not have enough rep.